# Format database listing of galleries

Tags: php

Hello I have the following code, which is sorting results from a database, how I can set it up so the results will be shown in 2 different columns, one for template.channel_item.php and one for template.channel_item.php in which 2 columns will be next to each other ?

```
if(is_array($array)) {
foreach($array as $row) {
    include($basepath.'/templates/template.channel_item.php');
    include($basepath.'/templates/template.channel_item_title.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(is_array($array)) {
foreach($array as $row) {

    echo '<div id="left">';
    include($basepath.'/templates/template.channel_item.php');
    echo '</div>';

    echo '<div id="right">';
    include($basepath.'/templates/template.channel_item_title.php');
    echo '</div>';
}
```

**CSS**

```
#right { float:left; width: 400px;}
#left { float:left; width: 400px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use loop

```
<div class="item-section" style="clear:both">
<div id="left-sidebar">
<?php include($basepath.'/templates/template.channel_item.php'); ?>
</div>

<div id="right-sidebar">
<?php include($basepath.'/templates/template.channel_item_title.php'); ?>
</div>
</div>
```

css

```
#left-sidebar, #right-sidebar { float: left; width: 400px; }
```